# how can i use a const function with "this"

Tags: c++, constants

```
double Triangle::area() const
{
    double a = this->_points.at(0).distance(this->_points.at(1));
    double b = this->_points.at(1).distance(this->_points.at(2));
    double c = this->_points.at(2).distance(this->_points.at(0));
    return ((sqrt((a + b + c)*(a + b - c)*(a - b + c)*(-a + b + c))) / (2*c));
}
```

i have this const function that need to return the area of a triangle, i found a formula that works for every type of triangle.
`_points` is a `std::vector<Point>` that contains 2D points with `x` and `y` parameters.
I have a `distance()` function that gives me the distance between two points.

I don't know how to get the triangle's area in another way and the function must be const, the visual studio marks the first "this" in each row, and it gives me that problem:

```
const Triangle *const this
Error: the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function
       object type is: const Point
```

`Point` is the class that has the `distance()` function and the declaration of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Perhaps your `Point::distance` function is not `const`.

Comment: this-> operator is used to refer to variables/functions located/initialized in the private section of your class.

Comment: @Bot Uhmm, what? In which way is your statement relevant regarding the `const` function?

Comment: @Bot, not only your statement is irrelevant, it's also incorrect. lol

Comment: my statement tells him that this operator can be and only can be used in const functions to refer to functions or variables/objects such as const function object types such as const point because data types don't match.

Comment: The this pointer is an implicit parameter to all member functions. Therefore, inside a member function, this may be used to **refer** to the invoking object. link - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_this_pointer.htm I am correct in my statement.

Comment: @Bot _"... refer to variables/functions located/initialized in the **private section** of your class"_ That's nonsense!

Comment: the distance function isn't const but it gets a 
(const &Point <name>) as an argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for your clarifying comment

> *"the `distance` function isn't const but it gets a (const &Point ) as an argument"*

The `Point` values accessed from your vector member variable have to be considered `const` in your code appearing inside the `const` member function

```
this->_points.at(1).distance(this->_points.at(2));
   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the 2nd signature in the `std::vector::at()` [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at), this one is actually called in your `area()` function.

This finally requires, that the `Point` class needs to declare a

```
double distance(const Point& pt) const;
                              // ^^^^^
```

member signature that it can be called from your `double Triangle::area() const` member function.

I suppose your `Point::distance()` function, doesn't change the `Point` instance in any way, thus it would be perfectly OK, just to add `const` to the signature appropriately.

---

> *"I don't know how to get the triangle's area in another way and the function must be const, the visual studio marks the first "this" in each row and it gives me that problem:"*
>
> *`const Triangle *const this`*

To explain a bit more in depth:

The `this` pointer will be evaluated to

1. `Triangle *const` in **non `const`** member functions
2. `const Triangle *const` for **`const`** member functions

The 1st form allows to modify the data members of `Triangle`.
The 2nd form denies this, unless the data member in question is marked as `mutable`.

Both forms (the `const` appearing after the `*`) deny, that you can modify the `this` pointer itself (e.g. trying something like `this = new Triangle();`)